# Use fitsio to rename a FITS file extension in Python

Tags: python, astropy

I am using the fitsio library trying to create a new fits file, insert a table from a dataframe df, and change a keyword. However, when I do that, my first extension has no name. I cannot figure out how to change the extension name.
Right now I am doing the following:

```
import fitsio

example_file = fitsio.FITS('example_test.fits', 'rw')
example_file.write(df.to_records(index=False))

example_file[1].write_key('My Key Name', key_name, comment="seconds")
example_file.close()
```

Comment: Found it: ```example_file.write(df_out.to_records(index=False), extname='My Extension Name')```

Comment: Can't you use `astropy`?

Comment: @MSH fitsio has some advantages in certain use cases over `astropy.io.fits`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`example_file.write(df_out.to_records(index=False), extname='My Extension Name')`